# C++ OpenGL, errors when linking, compiling

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-construction, linker, glut

Witam, 
nie potrafię sobie poradzić z błędami linkera chyba że kompilatora(i raczej to jest kompilator). Chciałem swoje stare projekty skompilować na nowo i poprawić programy, jednak nie potrafię przejść przez proces linkowania. 
w folderze z source.cpp posiadam dodatkowo 
Hello,
i cant move on with errors from linker, or compiler. I want to compile my old projects, but  i cant cope with errors.
in folder with source.cpp i have also

```
open32.dll 
glu32.dll 

glut32.dll (i download it) 
glut.h (si download it) 
glut.lib (i download it) 
glut.def (i think its not nessesery)
```

bach looks like

```
path %pathC:\MinGW\bin 
g++ -o program.exe main.cpp glut32.lib
```

and i get errors in every line where i use function from glut32.dll/opengl.dll, all errors are similar
C:\Users\Przemko\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4n2CuY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `glClearColor@16'

In MinGW\Include i have folder GL with headers:

```
glu.h 
gl.h 
glext.h
```

"i get it while installing MingW"

my source include

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "glut.h"
```

I need help, i dont remember how to link every item, i wish i have my old bash and libary, but i dont.

Answer (score 3):

You don't link with the actual OpenGL library, you need to add `-lGL` to your command:

```
$ g++ -o program.exe main.cpp glut32.lib -lGL
```

Comment: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lGL
but wait, i dont want to link item from "global repository", i want to have everything in project folder. then in near feature i will not have such problems

Comment: the idea is to _not_ keep everything in your project directory: then in the future, when you have multiple projects, you won't have to manually update all of them if you want to get a new OpenGL version

Comment: but when i want to use different version of OpenGL. but also when i link dll from system32 it also dont working

Comment: On Windows the library is called opengl32.dll, so it's `-lopengl32` not `-lGL`.

Comment: I try to compile this with **g++ -o program.exe main.cpp glut32.lib -L. -lglu32 -lglut32 -lopengl32** this library glu32.dll, glut32.dll and opengl32.dll i have in folder with source. but then i get error **./glu32.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to keep your `dll` files in `SysWOW64` folder instead of `System32` folder in case you have `x64` `libraries`.